# Binary Search Trees and Data with Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree function with 3 pieces of data in each node. They are classified by id numbers. They also hold "Name" and "Mark"

A certain function I'm having problem with is a name searching function, it looks like this:

```
def findName(tree,name):
    if tree==None:
        return None
    elif tree['name']==name:
        return True
    else:
        findName(tree['right'],name)
        findName(tree['left'],name)
```

I can always find the first name in a tree, but i can't find any onwards. If I input `findName(tree['right'],name)` in the python idle I get true if the name is in the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way for a function to actually return some data, is if it itself uses a `return` statement.  Your `else:` suite doesn't contain any `return` statements.

Comment: First off I love the username. :P and Yeah I assumed that since it was recursive it would be returning the True. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

on the else you would have to do something like:

```
return findName(tree['right'],name) or findName(tree['left'],name)
```

so that it searches in both branches and if it finds it in any of those branches the return value will be True

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are opensource binary search tree modules available; if your goal is to learn about BST's, by all means write your own, but if you're working on something that is amenable to opensource, you might want to try a canned module that's already been tested and debugged.

I have something kind of like a BST for Python at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/ .  It's actually a variant of a BST that doesn't require keys to be fed to the BST in a random order - it uses a random value on each node to scatter things.  To the programmer, it looks like a dictionary except the keys come back sorted when you iterate over them, and lookups aren't as fast as a dictionary (hash).

Treaps were discovered back in the late 80's, I believe, so they're a relatively recent bit of CS.  They're a very well-rounded datastructure; the more different ways you access the same data, the better off you are likely to be with a treap.

Actually, from what you've described, you might even be better served by just a dictionary (hash table) where the keys are your names.